sqlachemy self-referential many-to-many relation with foreign key on other class
I have the following models in sqlalchemy:
class UUIDMixin:
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class Location(Base, UUIDMixin):
  __tablename__ = "locations"

  predictions: Mapped[list[Prediction]] = relationship(
    back_populates="location",
    foreign_keys="Prediction.location_id",
  )


prediction_relations = Table(
    "prediction_relations",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("dependant_prediction_id", ForeignKey("predictions.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("underlying_prediction_id", ForeignKey("predictions.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Prediction(Base, UUIDMixin):
    __tablename__ = "predictions"

    location_id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("locations.id"))
    location: Mapped[Location] = relationship(
        back_populates="predictions", foreign_keys=[location_id]
    )
    underlying_predictions: Mapped[list["Prediction"]] = relationship(
        "Prediction",
        secondary=prediction_relations,
        primaryjoin="Prediction.id == prediction_relations.c.dependant_prediction_id",
        secondaryjoin="Prediction.id == prediction_relations.c.underlying_prediction_id",
        back_populates="dependant_predictions",
    )
    dependant_predictions: Mapped[list["Prediction"]] = relationship(
        "Prediction",
        secondary=prediction_relations,
        primaryjoin="Prediction.id == prediction_relations.c.underlying_prediction_id",
        secondaryjoin="Prediction.id == prediction_relations.c.dependant_prediction_id",
        back_populates="underlying_predictions",
    )

When I try to add a prediction that has an underlying prediction I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: predictions.location_id.
Is it possible to store them both together or do I have to commit the underlying prediction first before the dependant prediction can be commited?

I'm not sure this error is related to the many 2 many relationship.   Is this the actual code you are running?  Location doesn't seem to have a primary key, is it implied through Base somehow?  Also the error is related to the fact that a Predication was created without setting the location/location_id to a non-NULL value.  Should every prediction be required to have a location set or is that an accident?

both Location and Prediction inherit from UUIDMixin which adds the primary key. I edited the code snippet.
Yes, every prediction should have a location set. And all predictions that are connected through underlying_predictions will reference the same location.
